# Jmeter test with keystore works only for the first iteration of the loop

Tags: jmeter, iteration, ssl-certificate, keystore

I created a simple test where user logs in to the system using OpenAm and then logs out. I put my thread group to work in a loop and for the first iteration it works properly. But when it goes to the next iteration, my test fails, because someone else was trying to log in and of course he can't.

I have 15 user certificates and created .jks file based on them. User names are e.g. "hperfteste001" and so on.
I configured 'Keystore Configuration' config element and provided path and password in **system.properties** file

[image]

I added Cache Manager and Cookie Manager, where I checked `Clear cookies each iteration?` checkbox
I also added lines (I was trying various values with them, but didn't help):

```
https.use.cached.ssl.context=false

CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

I ran the test for 5 users in two loops
[image]

As you see, the first iteration works and proper user logs in. Here is the response message:

[image]

but in the next iteration test fails because it didn't pass the assertions. Some 'Guest' user was trying to logged in and also this login attempt was re-directed to different page, than the one in first iteration. Here is the response message:

[image]

But in the debug sampler I see that proper alias was read and I have certificate with such alias

[image]

[image]

It happens after first iteration of the loop and it doesn't matter for how many users I run this test.
I would really appreciate it if someone could help me, because I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is no certificate with alias of `hp7` in the keystore, you can check all certificates as:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore /path/to/your/keystore
```

or try getting the certificate with `hp7` alias:

```
keytool -list -keystore /path/to/your/keystore -alias hp7
```

if you get `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias does not exist` it means that there is no such an alias in the keystore and you need to re-visit the way you created it.

More information: [keytool utility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html)

If you have problems with command-line tools you can consider using [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) which provides simple GUI interface to managing keys and certificates.

You may also find [How to Use Multiple Certificates When Load Testing Secure Websites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-multiple-certificates-when-load-testing-secure-websites) article useful

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for your response. I checked this Alias and I have such certificate:
"hp7, 31 may 2021, PrivatekeyEntry, Certificate fingerprint (SHA-256): xxx".
When I extend users to 10 in first iteration and run the test, user with this Alias will be able to log in. The problem is with later iterations.